# How do I configure a guest VM's static IP address automatically in Citrix XenServer?

Tags: virtualization, configuration, citrix, xenserver, provisioning

To facilitate automation of guest VM provisioning, how do I set (in a script) the IP address on a guest VM's NIC (or NIC's) once a new VM has booted?

Is there a way to "inject" `netsh` commands via the Citrix guest OS tools (for Windows for example) once the host has started?

Or can this be done via the Citrix API/SDK or the `xe` tools?

These are windows 2008 servers that have been sysprep'd so when the boot for the first time they have no IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like a very custom (and thus very high maintenance) solution. What about DHCP?

Comment: Can't use DHCP, the servers require static IP addresses.

Comment: Whats the requirement? You _can_ fix an IP address to a MAC (and thus to a NIC/server) with DHCP. Or is the requirement that there shouldn't be any DHCP server?